# RxJava2 subscribe is not called when mapping observable to completable

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-binding

I have a click event which needs to make a network request.

```
RxView.clicks(button)
    .flatMapCompletable({ x -> networkCall() })
    .subscribe(...)
```

The click is an Observable.
`networkCall` returns a Completable.
However the block inside `subscribe` is never called when i tap the button.

I've also tried

```
RxView.clicks(button)
    .flatMap({ x -> networkCall().toObservable<Void>() })
    .subscribe(...)
```

How can I get this to work so that each time I tap on the button, a network request is made and is then handled in the `subscribe`.

EDIT:

I haven't done the network stuff yet so currently it's just

```
public Completable networkCall() {
    Completable.complete();
}
```

So it's guaranteed to complete.

Comment: How do you override subscribe? I am not sure, but if you just override the `onNext` this might not work. Have you also overridden the `onComplete` function with your subscriber?

Comment: Regarding the docs, I would also say that flatmapCompletable is not the right option for you: Maps each element of the upstream Observable into CompletableSources, subscribes to them and waits until the upstream and all CompletableSources complete. -> `RxView.clicks` does not complete at all!
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapCompletable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

Comment: @Christopher I had a feeling `flatmapCompletable` wouldn't be appropriate which is why I also tried the second code block. I've overridden `onNext` and `onComplete` and just added logs and breakpoints in those methods and it doesn't hit either. However, even with the second code block, I'm still concerned since it might end the stream when `onComplete` is called from the network call.

Comment: Is my only option to nest the network call inside the subscribe of the click? So basically have two subscriptions?

Comment: @SunnySydeUp, are you sure your networkCall completed? please add the code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `flatMap` case needs items, otherwise its `onComplete` will never fire due to the already mentioned never-completing clicks source. For example:

```
RxView.clicks(button)
.flatMap({ x -> networkCall().andThen(Observable.just("irrelevant")) })
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
.subscribe({ v -> System.out.println(v)}, { e -> e.printStackTrace() })
```